# how to get a string manipulation?

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

How I'll assign the string x = "490.00 001.09 987.1 876.99" into

```
x1 = "490.00"
x2 = "001.09"
x3 = "987.1"
x4 = "876.99"
```

Please advice me.. tnx!

Comment: I believe there are enough answers :)

Comment: I would use the Split function-- somebody should probably use that an an answer.  :-)

Comment: Not a single regular expression answer.  I'm amazed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) which splits the string by a separator character into multiple parts. The default separator is any whitespace character:

```
 string x = "490.00 001.09 987.1 876.99";

 string[] parts = x.Split();

 string x1 = parts[0];
 string x2 = parts[1];
 string x3 = parts[2];
 string x4 = parts[3];
```

Answer (score 4):

In your **very specific** case, this will work:

```
var x = "490.00 001.09 987.1 876.99";
var parts = x.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

var x1 = parts[0];
var x2 = parts[1];
var x3 = parts[2];
var x4 = parts[3];
```

Comment: `Split` has [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) so you do not need to explicitly create the array.

Comment: @H.B.: Yeah, habit. I usually specify the culture options as the second parameter which I believe requires using an array as the first.

Comment: Yes, same for the usage of the `StringSplitOprtions` overload.

Answer (score 3):

For the case you mentioned you can split the string into an array using the [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method

```
var x = "490.00 001.09 987.1 876.99"
var xsplit = x.Split(' ');
var x1 = xsplit[0];
var x2 = xsplit[1];
var x3 = xsplit[2];
var x4 = xsplit[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do a string.split and split on a space character. If you want it set to different variables you could take the position of them within the resulting array.

Comment: @Yuck beat me to coding it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var xArray = "490.00 001.09 987.1 876.99".Split(' ');
```

Then access to elements as `xArray[0]`, `xArray[1]` etc.

Comment: `" "` is an invalid argument type for `Split`.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need individual variables? It's easy enough to split the string and reference each by its index in the resulting array:

```
string x = "490.00 001.09 987.1 876.99";
var xAsArray = x.Split();

var x1 = xAsArray[0];
var x2 = xAsArray[1];
// and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

string[] DiagnosisCodesParts = DiagnosisCodestemp.Split();